# Question about printing: displaying value reflecting change

Tags: c, formatting, cursor-position

I have some question about printing on C. Here is my code.

```
while(1)
{
    if(Button == 32)
    {
        break;
    }
        else
    {
        if(Button == 1)
            count += 1;
        if(btn_value == 2)
            count -= 1;
        if(btn_value == 4)
            count = 0;

        printf("%d\r", count);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}


for (int i=count;i>=0 ; i--)
{
    printf ("YOUR TIME : %02d\r", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is part of my main code. What I designed is to receive button input and change the value of the count correspondingly. What I want to do is to display the value of `count` in one line that continuously reflects change of `count`.

I mean, if current situation is

Result window

```
2
```

and if I give Button = 1, I want result to be

Result window

```
3
```

not

Result window

```
2
3
```

So I found some code to do this but when count exceeds 10 and return back to one digit(0~9),
the result shows

10 to 90, not 09. Also not 08 but 80. How can I handle this?

Comment: `printf("%d\r", count);` => `printf( "%02d\r", count );`.  The `02` means format a minimum field width of 2 characters, and left pad with `0` instead of a space.  That will overwrite the previous 2-character output.

Comment: `printf(" %-8d\r", count);`

Comment: Will using system("cls") before printing count work for you?

Comment: @VisakhVijayan: system() is quite heavy as it launches a shell which executes the requested command. So, at least two child processes would be launched upon each change on the screen. This is not reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite leftovers by spaces, like this:

```
printf("YOUR TIME : %d \r", i);
```

Do you see the space character between `%d` and `\r`?

Some notes:

- You already had `%02d`, but this does not match your description of the wrong output.
- I would place `\r` at the beginning of the format string, as it seems more logical to me.
- If the output shall be overwritten with another text after the loop finished, I would keep the `\r` where it is now, and `printf("FINISHED       \n");` or `puts("FINISHED       ");` with enough spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If the output terminal supports them, it is possible to use ANSI escape sequences as presented [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php). For examples:

- To erase the line from the cursor position: ESC[K
- To make the cursor go N columns backward: ESC[ND

Here is a small example program displaying a counter from 0 to 19 at the same position every seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int count = 0;

  do {

    printf("%d", count);
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(1);
    count = (count + 1) % 20;

    // Go 2 columns backward + Erase the line
    // (033 is the octal ASCII code of ESC)
    printf("\033[%dD\033[K", 2);
    
  } while(1);

  return 0;
}
```